# htaccess redirect old URL to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

On my website for SEO purpose the link  to `hotel.php?hotel_id=104` is changed to `parkgrand.html`
and changed htaccess to refer to the same script

code : `RewriteRule ^parkgrand\.html$ /hotel.php?hotel_id=104`

Till this it works fine. But I want if some user still accesses the old url i.e. hotel.php?hotel_id=104 then he should get automatically redirected to parkgrand.html and  user agent should get a response 301

So, the code now becomes

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/hotel.php
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^hotel_id=104
RewriteRule ^hotel.php /parkgrand.html [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^parkgrand\.html$ /hotel.php?hotel_id=104
```

But this is causing a redirect loop and the intended page doesn't gets displayed to the user. 
Can anyone tell me what should be the correct code for this.

Comment: Answer below by @Prix is pretty good and should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
# Redirect /hotel.php?hotel_id=104 to /parkgrand.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+hotel\.php\?hotel_id=104[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /parkgrand.html? [R=302,L]
```

Change from `R=302` to `R=301` once you confirm it is working to avoid caching.

Keep in mind you may have been cached from your previous attempts since you're using `R=301`, I will recommend you to test the above using a different browser to make sure its working in case your usual browser is cached.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me from doing nasty coding.